# What does the two different sizes of fetched files mean in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

When opening the developer tool of Chrome(version = 15), under Network tab, there are two different sizes of the files fetched from server. I'd like to know what do they mean.

Please see the files attached.

[image: Chrome inspector]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the top number (Size) is the size of the request itself. The bottom number (Content) is the size of the response. Here's a very basic image to demonstrate:

[image]

That particular request is from this very page (to `careers.stackoverflow.com/ad/js`).

Comment: Thanks James. One more question, in my screenshot, the Size is bigger than Content. As to my knowledge, the request is small. Why it looks so big?

Comment: I wondered that too... unfortunately, I don't know the answer to that! Sorry. If someone else does, hopefully they will comment here :)